# How to sign window forms application, as it is not an option for me

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I would like to be able to sign my code, mainly just so windows defender won't complain about it on other computers but it needs to be signed nonetheless.

Convienently, visual studio provides an easy way to do that! Unless you're me...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym2LM.png

The sign the click one manifests thing is unavaliable, and the sign the assembly, well, when I create a password key, well, lets just say it makes major uncircumventable roadblocks.

So my question is -
How can I sign my windows forms app, and why is what I would assume to be the tradional method greyed out?d

Comment: Can you provide a link to the guide you are following?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-enable-clickonce-security-settings?view=vs-2019#to-enable-clickonce-security-settings

Comment: On that guide it says to go to the security tab, but I have no security tab?

Comment: What exact version of visual studio and what kind of project is it? console, wpf, addin, asp.net?

Comment: Oops sorry I had thought it said in the title, its a wf, and the vs version is Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.3

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know/gotten-to signing software requires a [x.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) certificate. I've never bought one or an SSL certificate for serving HTTPS, but I'm assuming they are similar, so maybe you can buy them at the same place...?

I just posted the Microsoft link [Add an exclusion to Windows Security](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26), it's the best I can do right now.

Comment: Yep, I already have a certificate, I'm just having a hard time using it with my app

Comment: Good luck to you.